# JWT bearer token not being validated correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication in my WebApi service. I started by adding the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
});
services.AddAuthorization();
```

And:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The client sends his credentials and I am generating a token as follows:

```
private string GenerateJsonWebToken(Client user)
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        user.Audience,
        new[] {
            new Claim("Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Name),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        },
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3600),
        signingCredentials: credentials);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

I'm using `Flurl` to send the requests as follows:

```
var token = await baseUrl
    .AppendPathSegment(loginUrl)
    .PostJsonAsync(new
    {
        Id = clientId,
        Secret = clientSecret,
        Audience = audience
    })
    .ReceiveString();

var test = await baseUrl
    .AppendPathSegment(protectedUrl)
    .WithOAuthBearerToken(token)
    .GetStringAsync();
```

I then have a controller action with the `Authorize` attribute. When the client calls this endpoint with the bearer token in the header, the token is not being validated (I tried sending bogus text as a token).

Am I missing something?

Comment: `app.UseAuthentication()` should be placed between `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`

Comment: *the token is not being validated* - what does this mean? Are you getting a 40x HTTP response code? Is the controller action entered when it shouldn't? An exception thrown?

Comment: The way to verify a signature is to first paste the key into the secret key field and then paste the token to the left part of the debugger. If your key is actually Base64 encoded (i.e. a binary secret that is stored in Base64 encoded form), you should tell jwt.io by checking the "secret base64 encoded" checkbox.  That's why when you click on 'secret base64 encode', the message changes to signature verified. How do you send your token ? By swagger or postman or ?

Comment: The action is entered when it's suppised not to. No exception thrown. I'm sending my token in C# using Flurl.

Comment: Could you share you c# code about using Flurl ? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at `token` .  What's your `token` look like ? What's  your `baseUrl` ?  Do you try 
`var test  = await protectedUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(token).GetStringAsync();` ?

Comment: I do get a token and I do get result from the protected url. Even if a use a fake token I still get results (which should not happen). It must be some missing setting in the resource api.

Comment: May I ask where your JWT token is stored?

Comment: @Paul Nowhere: I set it in the request header and the JWT bearer middleware should validate it.

Comment: " It must be some missing setting in the resource api. " If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.